# Show that two functions are linearly independent.

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I show that $f$ defined by $f(x)=2x$ and $g$ defined by $g(x)=|x|$ is a linearly independent list in $\mathbb{R}^{[-5,5]}$?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $a(2x)+b(|x|)=0$ for all $x \in [-5,5]$. Put $x=1$ to get $2a+b=0$ and $x =-1$ to get $-2a+b=0$. Can you show now that $a=b=0$?

Answer (score 0):

Two functions are linearly independent if neither one is a multiple of the other.

If $f$ and $g$ were linearly dependent, $f(x)=ag(x)$ for some constant $a$.

Can you show that no $a$ exists such that $f(x)=ag(x)$ on the entire interval $[-5,5]$?